# Defmacro that expands to defsetf

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, backticks

I'm having some trouble with some nested backquotes in CL. I'm trying to create a macro `define-access` that takes two parameters, `F` and `A`. `define-access` should define a function and setf expansion for symbol `F` that acts just like the respective function and setf for `A`. The current code is as follows.

```
(defmacro define-access (F A)
  (let ((X (gensym))
        (Y (gensym)))
    `(progn
       (defun ,F (,X)
         (,A ,X))
       (defsetf ,F (,X) (,Y)
         `(setf (,A ,,X) ,,Y)))))
```

The problem arises at the bottom, with the nested backquote.

The desired behavior of `define-access` is as follows.

```
(define-access fname car)
=> (progn (defun fname (x) (car x))
          (defsetf fname (x) (y) `(setf (first ,x) ,y)))
```

But right now, according to `macroexpand-1`, I'm getting the following (line breaks added for sanity).

```
(PROGN (DEFUN FNAME (#:G22490) (CAR #:G22490))
       (DEFSETF FNAME (#:G22490) (#:G22491)
           (LIST 'SETF (LIST A #:G22490) #:G22491)))
```

What am I not understanding about the backquote operator, or how should I approach this sort of problem?

Comment: You know that `define-access` is identical to the short form of `defsetf`, right? `(defsetf fname car)`

Comment: FYI, the way to use your macro is `(define-access fname car)` not `(define-access (fname car))`

Comment: @Barmar Right, sorry. Fixed that. Fortunately, the expansion was correct anyway.

Comment: @Barmar Is it? defsetf (as far as I knew) defined a write function to be called when setf is used on a getter, not a synonym (i.e. `(defsetf car rplaca)` would define something close to `car`'s setf)

Comment: Sorry, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another comma before `A` in the nested backquote, so it expands to the value of the variable outside the outside the outer backquote. And then it needs to be quoted to keep from evaluating that as a variable. So it becomes `,',A`

```
(defmacro define-access (F A)
  (let ((X (gensym))
        (Y (gensym)))
    `(progn
       (defun ,F (,X)
         (,A ,X))
       (defsetf ,F (,X) (,Y)
         `(setf (,',A ,,X) ,,Y)))))
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/99Mhsb)

Comment: Hm... that seems closer to what I'm looking for, but I get "variable CAR has no value" when trying to use the `setf` expander.

Comment: Fix that. With your new edit, it works flawlessly. Thank you very much.